# Apple Developer program Membership Enrolment

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-id

I have enrolled as an Individual / Sole Proprietor / Single Person Business type for the membership programme. Is it now possible to change the type to Company / Organization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't the Apple developer program's support team.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.

> Can I switch my membership from an individual to an organization?
>
> Yes, if you are the founder/co-founder of the organization. To start
>   the conversion process, please contact us. You may be asked to submit
>   business documents to verify your company's identity.

For reference:
https://developer.apple.com/support/account/

Steps:
Please check below link. Hope it would be helpful: [Moving from Individual to Company] http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/moving-from-individual-to-company/

Comment: Can you please share the procedure link(s)?

Comment: Please check below link. Hope it would be helpful:
[Moving from Individual to Company]
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/moving-from-individual-to-company/

Comment: @Barath Eswer: Did it help?